# remove only double quotes from string before and after square bracket

Tags: android, regex, string, replace

I am trying to remove double quotes before square bracket like "[
and I am using following code to do it but it says illegal escape charecter.

```
  str = str.replace("\[","[");
```

I want to remove only double quotes ie `"` which is only before square bracket ie `[`. Please guide me.

Comment: `str = str.replace("\"(?=\\[)","");` is one of possible solutions.

Comment: To remove `]"` just escape `]` as above. `str = str.replace("\\]\"","]");`

Comment: thank you..working properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"\\[", "[");
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` do the job. Using `replace`, you don't have to cope with regular expressions. Don't get confused by the name. In fact `replace` replaces **all** occurrences, not just the first.

```
str = str.replace("\"[", "[");
```